# Deleted site collections showing in search results after multiple full crawls

Tags: search-results, crawling

I am experiencing an issue where search results are showing deleted site collections after multiple full crawls.  I've been searching around and trying different things, but so far nothing has worked.

I created a modified core search results web part that shows us all site collections that we have access to.

(See: http://jeffreypaarhuis.com/tag/core-search-results/)

The search results show deleted site collections.  When you click on a once-valid URL, this is what you see:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2015 14:33:55 GMT
Connection: close
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried an index reset or restarting search service?

Comment: Hi Amal, thanks for the response.  Your response is correct.  Resetting the index fixed the issue.  I also made sure to delete the deleted sites as an elevated search account can see weird things (unpublished documents, recycle bin contents, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If deleted site collections still showed in the search result, then make sure following things.

- A full Crawl against the content source(which belongs to deleted site collections)
- If after couple of crawls items still Showed in the result then reset the search index.

Another thought, please make sure the deleted sites also removed from Central admin...run the get-spdeletedsites and check if the deleted site listed their.

Comment: The index reset fixed the problem.  I also made sure that deleted sites were actually deleted first.  Thanks!